# Spelling changes

Tags: orthography

There was a word I learned to spell when I was 11 in which there was a silent G.  It is no longer used.  Right now I cannot remember the word, but I am interested in finding out how to locate U.S. words whose spelling has changed in the last 60 years.

Comment: Americans in particular have become much more accepting of ***thru*** instead of ***through*** in (semi-)formal contexts. And more and more people discard the final letter in ***-ing*** forms (usually, but not always, replacing it with an apostrophe).

Comment: To give another example, "donut" is now a more commonly accepted spelling of "doughnut"

Comment: @geekahedron: Interestingly, per [Google n-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doughnut%2C+donut&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoughnut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdonut%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdoughnut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdonut%3B%2Cc0), _doughnut_ is still more common, but both terms have been gaining in popularity.

Comment: And the earliest reference I could find to "donut" as an alternative to "donut" was [this 1913 Bulletin of the United States Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://books.google.com/books?id=EXdIAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22donut%22&pg=PA436#v=onepage&q=%22donut%22&f=false) document.

Comment: @Zack Google does not index shop fronts, street adverts, etc.

Comment: @vectory: Does such an index exist? If not, then claiming that "donut""has surpassed "doughnut" would be a matter of speculation, no?

Comment: 'Donut' would not be pronounced the same as 'doughnut'. It would be  'doo-nut'.

Comment: @NigelJ - You're funny...

Comment: @geekahedron Even Merriam-Webster clearly indicates that [*donut*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/donut) is the *less common* spelling of the word. That spelling is *relatively* more popular in the US (than the UK), but even in the US, *doughnut* remains more common.

Comment: What I intended, alluding to FumbleFingers's phrasing, was that "donut" is more commonly accepted [than it used to be]. Clearly, I should have worded my comment differently to avoid this confusion. I have no idea which of the two spellings is more commonly accepted than the other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because asking for resource recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Leaving this as a comment rather than a question, because it doesn't answer the OP's question ("how to locate..."), but there are donut references in [1887](https://archive.org/details/03036944.2378.emory.edu/page/n87?q=%22a+donut%22), [1877](https://archive.org/details/argonaut58591906sanf/page/n391?q=%22a+donut%22), [1868](https://archive.org/details/joshbillingsoni00billgoog/page/n28?q=%22a+donut%22), [1858](https://archive.org/details/prairierockymounta00vant/page/160?q=donuts), and [1849](https://archive.org/details/abudgetwitandhu00valegoog/page/n40?q=donuts).